# delete first N characters conditionally using sed or awk or anything

Tags: bash, awk, sed, echo, tr

I am trying to delete zeros at the start of the line till fourth characters. If zero is occurring beyond 4th position then need not to delete it. I am not able to achieve this correctly.

## Condition:

```
01230 <------Delete 1 zero at start.
001230 <-----Delete 2 zeros at start.
0001230 <----Delete 3 zeros at start.
00001230<----Delete 4 zero at start.
000001230<---Delete 4 zero at start and leave 1, output 01230
1234560<-----Delete nothing.
```

Example:

## INPUT file:

```
cat file
0000abc0
00abcde0
0abcede0
00000abcede0
```

## Expected output:

```
abc0
abcde0
abcede0
0abcede0
```

What have been already tried:(which of course did not helped)

```
    cat file |sed 's/^[0]//g' <----This just delete one zero at the start
    000abc0
    0abcde0
    abcede0
    0000abcede0

    cat file | sed 's/^[0][0][0][0]//g'<---THis only works for line having 4 zeros.
    abc0
    00abcde0
    0abcede0
    0abcede0

cat file | sed 's/^[0]*//g' <-----Removes all the zeros at start. 
abc0
abcde0
abcede0
abcede0

cat file | sed 's/0//g'{4} <------I am lost what it do!!
000abc
00abcde0
0abcede0
000abcede
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `{}` to specify number of occurances and `-r` to allow extended regexp syntax:

```
sed -r 's/^0{1,4}//g'
```

Comment: @krzyk , it worked .Thanks. Will accept it in few minutes.

Comment: And not using extended regex at all is most portable.

Comment: @sjsam My sed (debian) doesn't have `-E` option, so it is not portable enough

Comment: @krzyk : Even my debian sed doesn't have that, but it works for me. Have you tried it out?

Comment: @123 : Not in this case though.

Comment: @mona_sax They still do different things, it's just that they conveniently produce the same output for this very specific case.

Comment: @123 : Well yes ! I thought in  `{,4}` at the least 1 time is implied but my test results proved otherwise.. It means none to 4 times. Eye-opener indeed.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Deletes from one up to four zeros at the start of the line.

```
gawk '{gsub(/^0{1,4}/,"")}1' file
abc0
abcde0
abcede0
0abcede0
```